# Overload matrix multiplication for S3 class in R

Tags: r, class, matrix, operator-overloading

How to I overload the matrix multiplication operator in `R`? I have been able to do it with most other operators (using Ops), but with matrix operations I get this error:

```
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Here is a minimum working example:

```
speed = function(x){
    structure(list(y = x),
              class = "speed")
}

m = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol = 2)
s = speed(m)

# Addition works fine
`+.speed` = function(e1, e2){ e1$y + e2 }

s + 10

# But matrix multiplication doesn't
`%*%.speed` = function(e1, e2){ e1$y %*% e2 }

s %*% c(1,2)
```

Comment: If 'speed' is a class,then you do Not want to define a 'speed' function. You might consider defining an as.speed function.

Comment: @42- Thx for the feedback. Changing the name of the constructor doesn't seem to change the behavior though.

Comment: Note that \`%*%.speed\`(s, c(1,2)) does in fact work. I'm not familiar enough with overloading the `Primitive`s to know how to make that work.

Comment: @42- I disagree, it’s good practice to have constructors that mirror the class name (as appropriate).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ok, and granted that `matrix` and `list` are good R counter-examples to my claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because the `%*%` is not an S3 generic function by default. You can get around this by making this so.

```
`%*%.default` = .Primitive("%*%") # assign default as current definition
`%*%` = function(x,...){ #make S3
  UseMethod("%*%",x)
}
`%*%.speed` = function(e1, e2){ e1$y %*% e2 } # define for speed

s %*% c(1,2)
     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]   10
```

You could view Hadley's book if you wanted additional info on this [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html)

Edited in light of comment below.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering if  `%*%.default` = .Primitive("%*%")  is be better than `%*%.default` = `%*%`. Thoughts?

Comment: @dudu I shouldn't have thought it matters since `%*%` calls the `.Primitive` anyway. Happy to be proved wrong by someone but I can't recall ever having worried about it in similar situations in the past and as far as I know have never run into issues.

Comment: It seems to matter if your snippet gets executed more than once. The second time around, `%*%.default will be defined as the S3 method instead of the .Primitive("%*%")`.